# How can i obtain a temporary mssql database with test containers using a specially modified JDBC URL?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, integration-testing, testcontainers, mssql-jdbc

I want to obtain a temporary mssql database to execute some tests, currently i am using h2 for the purpose but because it does not support stored procedures i want to start using the test containers, how can i obtain such database through the jdbc url in my application-test.yaml as i do for the h2:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:master;MODE=MSSQLServer;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dbo\;SET SCHEMA dbo
```

I tried to find a solution for this in the https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/ documentation but i dont find any for mssql.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#using-testcontainers-with-a-fixed-version ?

Comment: yes as i mentioned I don't see a specific configuration for sql server here :(

Comment: I see, can you try `jdbc:tc:sqlserver:<version>:///databaseName` or `jdbc:tc:sqlserver:2017-CU12://hostname:hostport;databaseName=databasename`

Comment: Thanks, this worked and instantiated the mssql server, but i stumbled on another problem on a macOS with m1 chip, it just not supports the sql server :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hostless JDBC url can be used. Using spring boot the following property should be set `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:sqlserver:latest:///`. Read more about [Testcontainers MSSQL server module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mssqlserver/).

See an example [here](https://github.com/eddumelendez/testcontainers-samples/blob/main/spring-boot-sqlserver-flyway/src/test/java/com/example/sqlserverdemo/HostLessTest.java#L13)